# Why is the gradient text not being shown over the border fill? CSS

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

I was using a site called http://css3buttongenerator.com/ and added a text gradient but for some reason I'm not sure it's not showing all the css coding on the page.

```css
.button {
  background: linear-gradient(330deg, #e05252 0%, #99e052 25%, #52e0e0 50%, #9952e0 75%, #e05252 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60;
  -moz-border-radius: 60;
  border-radius: 60px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #e05252 0%, #99e052 25%, #52e0e0 50%, #9952e0 75%, #e05252 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="button" href="course.html">Start</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.button` CSS Rule you overridden the `background` property.

```
.button {
    /* first background */
    background: linear-gradient(330deg, #e05252 0%, #99e052 25%, #52e0e0 50%, #9952e0 75%, #e05252 100%); 

    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60;
    -moz-border-radius: 60;
    border-radius: 60px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 60px;

    /* again background here*/
    background: #000;

    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Remove second background and it will work.

Comment: So I removed the 2nd background but now all I see on the button is the text and not both the text and the border fill. Is there something I am still doing wrong?